# Help finding a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm a little bit lost here; I need to find a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\ker(T)\cap\text{Im}(T)\neq\left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace$.

I have been looking for it all day, but any linear transformation I choose, I get $\ker(T)\cap\text{Im}(T)=\left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace$. Any help or idea will be really helpful.

Comment: Have you tried in $\mathbb R^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $T$ maps $(1,0,0)$ to $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ to $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ to $(0,0,1)$.

Then what do you get for $\ker(T)\cap\text{Im}(T)$?

Comment: It can't be, right? I mean, a linear transformation carry linear independent sets to linear independent sets

Comment: No, [linear independence does not need to be preserved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18678/linear-independency-before-and-after-linear-transformation); for example, consider the linear transformation that maps all the vectors to $\mathbf 0$

Comment: You'r right! and also te mapping in this case is linear independent, and I get that $\left\lbrace(1,0,0)\right\rbrace\in\ker(T)\cap\text{Im}(T)$ thank you so much!!!